# Jquery Mobile on buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

hey guys i have this code here everything seems to work fine except one problem...
i have a j query mobile pop up button in the code and it is not working as a button it actually isnt even functioning at all
is it something with my scripiting? 
or is it something that is interfering with my background?

I also tried to CDN the jquery scripts and Jquery mobile scripts but then my google chrome gives me a loading wheel forever and doesn't display any of the jquery stuff

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
<style>

   body {

  background-image: url(myhostedwebsiteurl.jpeg);


  background-position: center center;


  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  background-attachment: fixed;


  background-size: cover;


  background-color: #464646;
}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/csc" href="additionbutton.css"/> 

</head>
<body>


<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
  <h1 style="text-align:center"> <font face="comic sans ms" color= #F781F3><b> <marquee> blah blah</marquee></b></h1>
  </div>

 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">


<a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">About the Game</a>

  <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
    <p>text goes here but its not working </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: use bootstrap: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oLxxz9h4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, although not very clean - but that doesn't matter here.

I just copied and pasted your snippet to test it out and it works as expected, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pteb94xa/).

Just make sure, that the script files are loaded properly and you have the correct jQuery version (currently 1.11.1 for jQuery mobile compatibility).

To use all the scripts from CDNs, put this in your head in exactly this order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tested your code, along with the latest version of JQuery 2.1.3, and the latest JQuery Mobile CDNs: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1v946soo/

Included a few code fixes and cleanups:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <div data-role="header">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <h1 style="text-align:center">
            <font face="comic sans ms" color= #F781F3>
                <b>
                    <marquee> blah blah</marquee>
                </b>
            </font>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">About the Game</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
            <p>text goes here but its not working</p>
            <br />
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If this is still not working for you, please provide more details. Include the browser you are testing with and version, what errors if any appear in the console, and what steps would need to be taken to replicate the issue.